# Evidence for the claim that placing Gide's works in the Index of Forbidden Books scandalised the author's admirers?

Tags: french-language, censorship, andre-gide

The French author André Gide (1869 – 1951) was awarded the Nobel Prize in Literature in 1947. The author died in February 1951; in the following year, the [Vatican placed his works on the Index of Forbidden Books](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Andr%C3%A9_Gide&oldid=968958874#1930s_and_1940s). The [French Wikipedia article about the author](https://fr.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Andr%C3%A9_Gide&oldid=173931477#Mort) contains additional unsourced statements about this decision:

> L'ensemble de son œuvre est mis à l'Index par le Vatican en 1952<sup>47</sup>. Cette nouvelle scandalise les admirateurs enthousiastes de l'écrivain<sup>[réf. souhaitée]</sup>. Quant à ses détracteurs, qui pourtant l'attaquent avec violence, ils ne sont guère convaincus de l'utilité d'une telle discrimination<sup>[réf. souhaitée]</sup>.

Translation:

> In 1952, the entirety of his oeuvre is placed on the Index by the Vatican. This news scandalises the author's enthusiastic admirers. As far as his detractors are concerned, who attacked him violently, they are hardly convinced of the utility of this act of discrimination.

There is no source for the statement about his admirers, nor for the part about his detractors. The English Wikipedia, referenced above, does not mention these reactions at all. Neither does the [German Wikipedia article](https://de.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Andr%C3%A9_Gide&oldid=202524089#Der_Zweite_Weltkrieg_und_die_Nachkriegszeit), which adds, however, that the Vatican's action implied a recognition of the importance of Gide's work.

Can any sources for the reactions described above be found?

PS: The [Index Librorum Prohibitorum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_Librorum_Prohibitorum#Abolition_(1966)) was abolished 14 years later.